# js - check if string doesn't contain given characters

Tags: javascript, string, validation

I need to validate username that could not contain these characters:

```
var restricted = [' ','`','~','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','+','=','|','\\',"'",'"',']','[','{','}',':',';','<',',','>','?','/',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

How could I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to ONLY allow alphabetical characters. A simple regular expression will do.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(usernameString);
```

Comment: I'm afraid your method is not gonna work in the case of utf8 string. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You might want to show how to incorporate a check for a min length (a password shouldn't really have a maximum length, other than practicality to my mind).

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*$/
```

Change the `*` to `+` if you don't want to allow empty matches.

#### References:

[Character classes (`[...]`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Anchors (`^` and `$`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Repetition (`+`, `*`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

The `/` are just delimiters, it denotes the start and the end of the regex. One use of this is now you can use [modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var restricted= [' ','`','~','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','+','=','|','\\',"'",'"',']','[','{','}',':',';','<',',','>','?','/',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var s = "astring";
var contains = false;
for(var i = 0, ceiling = restricted.length; i < ceiling; i++) {
    if(s.indexOf(restricted[i]) != -1) {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}
alert("a restricted character was" + (contains ? "" : "n't") + " found");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a specific set of characters (ie the reg exp solution isn't appropriate), you probably have to loop through the array and test each element in the Restricted string.
Note if you're concerned about speed, it'll be quick because you're just comparing values.

```
var restricted = [' ','`','~','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','+','=','|','\\',"'",'"',']','[','{','}',':',';','<',',','>','?','/',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function checkRestricted (sTest) {
// returns true if the string is valid, false if any restricted chars found
var bValid-true 
for (var i=0;i:restricted.lenght;i++)
  {
     if (sTest.indexOf(restricted[i]) >-1) {bValid=false}
  }

return bValid;
}
```

Note that I've just typed this in without verifying it but it looks ok to me